# How to calculate the age of a person?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, time

For example, I need to calculate the time past since 1996-11-03 (yy/mm/dd) until now.
I need to do it in MC visual c++ in windows form app. The user will enter the year, month, day in 3 different texbox'es. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Yup, read the documentation found here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w4ddyt9h(v=vs.100).aspx - look at the function names for a few hints. Also, consider working the problem backwards. I.e work out how to get from a particular result back to a particular input. (It can be the fastest way to navigate the help docs for unfamiliar subjects)

Comment: Nope, no ideas. I think this is a NP Hard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may this will help you....

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        system("TITLE how old are you?");
        system("color f3");
        int yearnow,yearthen,monthnow,monththen,age1,age2;

        cout<<"\t\t\tEnter the current year and month \n\t\t\t(eg. 1997, enter, 7, enter):\n ";
        cin>>yearnow;
        cin>>monthnow;
        cout<<"Enter your birthyear and month: \n";
        cin>>yearthen;
        cin>>monththen;

        if(monththen >12 || monththen<1)
            return 1;

        if(monththen > monthnow){
             age1=yearnow-yearthen-1;
             age2=(12-monththen) + monthnow;
        }else{
             age1=yearnow-yearthen;
             age2=12-monththen;
        }
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tYou are "<<age1<<" year and "<<age2<<" moth old";
        system("pause>>void");
    }
```